# Get and post methods with different names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have an action method called New.  When form validation succeeds then I want Create to handle the request.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
   // Code
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   // Code
}
```

I have 2 questions regarding this.  Firstly, how do I modify my Html.BeginForm to handle the above?  I tried the following but I get an error, it is looking for the physical file Create (News is my controller name):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News"))
{
    <!-- Code -->
}
```

Secondly, how do I prevent a user from typing in /News/Create in the URL.  Create should handle only my post requests coming from New.

UPDATE:
I managed to get something working.  The original URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:33947/News/New
```

After I click the submit button and validation fails then the URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:33947/News/Create
```

Why does it do this?  I want it to stay:

```
http://localhost:33947/News/New
```

Here is my action method code:

```
public ActionResult New()
{
   return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewsViewModel newsViewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("New", newsViewModel);
   }

   return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post))
```

You cannot prevent user from typing address manually, but you can add another Create action marked with [HttpGet] attribute which will show user the error page. Anyway, your current Create action method will not handle such requests. Probably user will get standard File not found error in this case.

**UPDATE:** `Html.BeginForm("Create", "News")` means to submit the form to action "Create" of the controller "News", so it works as it should. If you want to submit to /News/New, replace it with `Html.BeginForm("New", "News")`.

Comment: You can make it a bit shorter, you don't need the FormMethod.Post, since post is the default value.

Comment: Then how do I get create to handle my request?

Comment: Do you mean you want to submit the form to Create, but the URL looks like /News/New?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, instead of:

```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("New", newsViewModel);
   }
```

you should use :

```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return RedirectToAction("new");
   }
```

Now this has the undesired side affect that your Modelstate is lost. (no validation errors are shown in your form.
To fix this add the `ModelStateToTempData` attribute to both your `new` and `create` action.
This attribute  come as part of http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/ .

Comment: Thanks. Is this best practices doing it this way? Don't they both do the same thing? If so why then change?

Comment: Check out : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get   . This pattern helps in preventing the F5/Refresh double form submission.